# How to edit my git command to output requested data using a comma as a separator

Tags: sed, git

I'm running this code below:

```
git rev-list --objects --all |
  git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' %(id)' |
  sed -n 's/^blob //p' |
  sort --numeric-sort --key=2 |
  gcut -c 1-12,41- |
  $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest
```

to output large data files in a git repo. The output looks something like this:

```
ne3ee2e43e1x 1.0MiB path/to/large/files.png ID
```

I would like to use a semi-colon as a delimiter between each datapoint called in the command. So the expected output would be like this:

```
ne3ee2e43e1x; 1.0MiB; path/to/large/files.png; ID
```

UPDATE:

Tried doing the following based off Marcus' answer.

```
git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype);%(objectname);%(objectsize);%(rest)' | sed -n 's/^blob //p' | awk '$2 >= 2^20' | sort --numeric-sort --key=2 | gcut -c 1-12,41- |$(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=1 --round=nearest
```

But this doesn't replicate anything in my end.

Comment: have you tried piping the output of `numfmt` into  `sed 's/,/;/g'`? That will convert all commas to semi-colons.

Comment: BTW, instead of using `$(command...)` in the middle of a pipeline, it's easier to read if use an alias or function, e.g. `command -v gnumfmt > /dev/null && alias numfmt=gnumfmt`.  If it's something you do often, do this in your `~/.bash_profile` (or equivalent for other shell).

Answer (score 0):

You specify the output format yourself with your `--batch-check` argument. So, add the semicolon in the format string! See the "batch output" section in the [`git cat-file` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file).

Also, why are you asking git for `objecttype` if all you're going to do with it it's blob output is remove it using sed?

Comment: Hi Marcus, do you happen to have an example? I'm trying to add the semi-colon to my --batch-check argument but the command is not returning anything.

Comment: I mean, the command you wrote has a `'` too many anyways, but correcting that, `git rev-list --objects --all |git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname);%(objecttype);'` works just fine for me

Comment: Thanks Marcus, can you please see my update and try testing the command that I am using? It's not able to run based off your recommendation. Was wondering if I missed something.

Comment: No I can't, sorry, I'm in bed. You can do your own debugging, simply by not trying a long long chain of pipes as one, but looking at the intermediate results. You don't need me to do that for you; it's as much work for me as for you.